# Regex for analytics - network domain containing/ending with .ac.uk or .sch.uk

Tags: regex, url, google-analytics, tld

Im setting up a custom report in google analytics to only show results where the network domain ends with .ac.uk or .sch.uk

(So we can see what universities have been on the website).

I just need to know what the regular expression would be for this?

[google analytics regex filter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JtHFx.png)

Comment: Try `\.(ac|sch)\.uk$`

Comment: Perfect, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use

```
\.(ac|sch)\.uk$
```

**Details**:

- `\.` - a dot
- `(ac|sch)` - either `ac` or `sch`
- `\.` - a dot
- `uk` - `uk` and
- `$` - end of string.